# Why ic_launcher larger or not fit in my phone, but perfect in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, icons

I import an image assets from png. And android studio create all image for all size.
Looks like perfect in android studio. But when I install, the phone, zoom image or use wrong size. I don't understand.

[image]

[image]

Thanks any idea.

Answer (score -1):

resize the image with photoshop or any image editing software and make the logo smaller. Maintain the image dimensions but make the contents smaller